# Append hidden type of input tag within ASPX?

Tags: asp.net

I want to have a hidden `input` tag in my HTML page , so i tried the following:

`<input type=hidden runat=server id=currentItem value="runtime_determinted" />`

But it won't got displayed on client , so I can't find it with javascript.

If the the tag isn't run at server side ,  I will have to append it to the end of the document , but which function should I use ?

Or is there any other solutions suitable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you use this instead, you can find it with javascript as well

```
<asp:HiddenField id="currentItem" runat="server" />
```

and then

```
var text = $('#<%= currentItem.ClientID %>').val();
```